# Is there any other way to store SFMC historical tracking data'(sends, open, clicks) other than using data view & tracking data extract

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views, history-tracking, data-extract

I want to store historical SFMC tracking data beyond 6 months. We can opt for data view export or tracking data extract to accomplish this. Do we have any other way in marketing cloud to store/fetch data beyond 6 months?

Comment: Not really, but why are you asking? What exactly is the use case behind this question?

Comment: Use case is to fetch/store historical SFMC tracking data. We wanted to ensure what are all the possible ways available and to choose the most recommended/effective way

Comment: The only other way is via SOAP API but using data views is far more easier: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/09/retrieve-tracking-data-since-account-inception-using-wsproxy/